# When to balance torque about centre of rotation as opposed to an instantaneous axis of rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When we consider a solid cylinder rolling down an incline we consider IAOR to be center of rotation but when the same cylinder is dragged across a rough horizontal surface by a horizontal force that acts at COM, the point of contact with floor becomes the IAOR. Why is this?

Comment: but the point of application of the force is same,and they roll in a similar fashion in both scenario why would the axis of rotation change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the reference frame of the rolling cylinder, then the IAOR is at the center of the cylinder. If you are in the reference frame of the ground, then the IAOR is at the point of contact between the cylinder and the ground. This can be seen by noticing that the point of contact between the cylinder and the ground has an instantaneous velocity of $0$ (otherwise, the cylinder would be slipping).

One does not need to know the IAOR to calculate torque, however. It is valid to balance torque about *any* point, not just the IAOR; this even includes points that are not in the interior of the object. Usually, though, torque is balanced about the IAOR because the calculations are nicer and more intuitive.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I have one more question. generally we are interested in a quantity with respect to an inertial frame so why is the torque on  a cylinder rolling down an incline calculated in the frame of the cylinder itself

Comment: @Monocerotis You can choose the center of the cylinder as your torque center and still calculate the torque in the reference frame of the ground. Either way should work, though.